# How to get previous value when component has been destroyed in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have component and render it in cycle (ngFor)
The component has an object

```
@Input() a = {
name: 'Bob'
}
```

After the change, it will reset its input parameters to the initial state
When the component has changed, I want to get the values ​​that were at its initial initialization
SCENARIO:
-> `@Input() a = {name: 'Bob'}` (init value)
-> then do something...  `this.a.name = 'Alice'`;
-> in the loop, the object changes
-> Once again, the component matters `@Input() a = {name: 'Bob'}` (init value)
I want to get the previous value after the component has been updated
that is 'Alice'

Answer (score 0):

From the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.a) {
    let chng = changes.a;
    let cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
    let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
  }
}
```

So, you'll need the `.currentValue` and `.previousValue` property to access current and previous values.

Edit:1

If the component gets destroyed you have to use some kind of state management - service with subject, sessionStorage, localStorage or something else

Edit: 2

You can extend the ngFor directive and add the state logic inside ngOnChanges.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngFor][ngForIn]'
})
export class NgForIn extends NgFor implements OnChanges {

  @Input() ngForIn: any;

  constructor(viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
              template: TemplateRef<NgForRow>,
              differs: IterableDiffers,
              cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    super(viewContainer, template, differs, cdr);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // Do something here
  }

}
```

Comment: No, it won't work, because the component will be destroyed in the loop and rendered again

Comment: trackBy will not work either, because it will destroy the component I need with the previous properties and they will become original again

Comment: I see, i have edited my answer